# Streamed Events api (Tigertext) in Python / Odoo / Postman

Tags: python-3.x, api, events, postman, odoo-14

I am trying to integrate Tigertext with Python / Odoo and I have almost completed it but I am stuck on **SSE streaming events API**. I have run all APIs in Postman but while try running events api in Postman, it takes more than 1 minute to give response and I have also tried this API in Python using requests library but it gives me error:

> requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read)", InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read))

Later I have read that Postman doesn't support SSE streaming event APIs. Below is the link:-

[Support for streamed responses link](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/5040)

It seems that the issue is still open. So wanted to know, if this solved or still it is in process?

I have tried running **slack's streaming events API** to make sure that if **streaming APIs** work with postman but even slack events API also doesn't work for the issue.

Also I have tried to implement **pre-request script** that is mentioned in the above link but it did not worked for me.

So is there anything i need to change in the script or any other solution to make it work in postman?

I have searched it more to check how it works in python and got a link mentioned below:-

[SSE events in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57913442/why-is-the-python-client-not-receiving-sse-events)

But that too didn't worked for me and got error while implementing in python even if i have added https in the url:-

> requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '<urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x7f79056d42e8>': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://<urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x7f79056d42e8>?

Is anything i am missing in the code mentioned in the url or i need to do any modification in this?